# C# Tcp communication Threadpool or asyn call

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, threadpool

I have a C# application which listens for incoming TCP connections and receive data from previously accepted connections. Please help me whether i use Threadpool or Async methods to write the program?? Note that, once a connection is accepted, it doesn't close it and continuously receive data from the connection, at the same time it accept more connections

Answer (score 1):

A threadpool thread works best when the code takes less than half a second and does not a lot of I/O that will block the thread.  Which is exactly the opposite scenario you describe.

Using Socket.BeginReceive() is strongly indicated here.  Highly optimized at both the operating level and the framework, your program uses a single thread to wait for *all* pending reads to complete.  Scaling to handle thousands of active connections is quite feasible.

Writing asynchronous code cleanly can be quite difficult, variables that you'd normally make local variables in a method that runs on the threadpool thread turn into fields of a class.  You need a state machine to keep track of the connection state.  You'll greatly benefit from the async/await support available in C# version 5 which allows you to turn those state variables back into local variables.  The little wrappers you find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17094024/17034) or [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx) will help a great deal.

Comment: As per my requirement, the server application listens for new connections and as each connections are accepted, it accepts fixed length data from accepted connections during 15 second intervals and also accept new connections

Comment: No idea what you are trying to tell me, I don't think it affects the answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends on what do you want to do with your connections. If you have unknown number of connections which you don't know how long they will be open, I think it's better to do it with async calls.

But if you at least know the avg. number of connection and the connections are short-term connections like a web server's connections, then it's better to do it with threadpool since you won't waste time creating threads for each socket.

Comment: Thnaks SAM...In my project, i don't know the number of connections and also it is not short term connections...I am not familiarized with async calls..Can u please help to understand it...

Comment: I think MSDN sample code for async calls is clear and will help you understand that.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you possibly can, don't use TCP/IP. I recommend you self-host WebAPI and/or SignalR instead. But if you do decide to use TCP/IP...

You should always use asynchronous APIs for sockets. Ideally, you want to be constantly reading from the socket and periodically writing (keepalive messages, if nothing else). What you *don't* want to do is to have time where you're only reading (e.g., waiting for the next message), or time where you're only writing (e.g., sending a message). When you're reading, you should be periodically writing; and when you're writing, you should be continuously reading.

This helps you detect half-open connections, and also avoids deadlocks.

You may find my [TCP/IP .NET Sockets FAQ](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Definately use `asynchronous` sockets...  It's never a good idea to block a thread waiting for `IO`.

If you decide you have high performance needs, you should consider using the `EAP` design pattern for your sockets.

This will allow you to create an asynchronous solution with a lower memory profile.  However, some find that using events with sockets is awkard and a bit clunky... if you fall into this category, you could take a look at this blog post to use .NET 4.5's `async/await` keywords with it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx#comments