# MSDN code for asynchronous TCP server is blocking when called from UI

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I have put Microsofts code <[here>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx) into a separate .cs file and call it from Form1 using the button below

```
private async void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.StartListening();
}
```

What would be the correct way to start the socket listener without the whole UI freezing

Comment: The example code you link to is designed to be run from a console, and it has an infinite while loop with no way to break out of it other than an error condition.  So that's why your UI is freezing.

Comment: That's an *old* sample. It doesn't take advantage of tasks awaiting. Unfortunately, the Socket class doesn't have any methods that return Task. You have to use `TaskFactory.FromAsync` to convert Begin/End calls to tasks, as [shown in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093206/high-performance-asynchronous-awaiting-sockets). The example becomes a lot simpler then

Comment: Why don't you use TcpListener instead of a socket? It provides task-based methods like [AcceptSocketAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocketasync(v=vs.110).aspx) and [AcceptTcpClientAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You can use BeginAccept : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll look into it. I'm just trying to make a client than can send a file to a different client

Answer (score 0):

Check out Task.Run(). Only using async won't make the whole method/event asynchronous. The example is not using a UI.

Comment: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action' is the error i'm getting from that.

Comment: try await Task.Run(()=>{Server.StartListening();});